# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException [java]

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have task to do and I have problem with one point and I'm getting error. I havve no idea how to repair it:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at test.main(test.java:29)

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class test
{

    static int size;
    static String[] productDescription;     

    public static void readProductsData()
    {
        Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Array size: ");                   
        size = data.nextInt();

        String[] productDescription = new String[size];

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Product name: ");
            productDescription[i] = data.next();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            System.out.println(productDescription[i]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        readProductsData();
        System.out.println(productDescription[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `productDescription`. Remove `String[]` before `productDescription` in `readProductsData`.

Comment: Oh well, didn't noticed. Thanks a lot.